# Python Dynamically Create String Based on Input

Tags: python, url, config

Looking for an elegant way to create a URL by reading in values from a config file.

If I have the following three fields in a config file:

```
query1=
query2=
query3=
```

And I want to add them to a BASE_URL if they exist, what is an elegant way to do this?

I know there is an ugly answer like:

```
url +='?query1={}'.format(param1) if param1 and Not param2 or param3
url +='?query1={}&query2={}'.format(param1,param2) if param1 and param2 and Not param3
etc...
```

Is there an elegant pythonic solution to this? A way to abstract this idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the fields in a dictionary as "key:value" pairs (you can read the file as dictionary using CSV reader) and append them to the base URL if needed:

```
fields = {'query1' : 'value1', 'query2' : '', 'query3' : 5, ...}
if fields: # Avoid null fields
    url += '?' + '&'.join('{}={}'.format(k,v) for k,v in fields.items() if v)
# '...?query1=value1&query3=5'
```

Comment: Thanks I think I personally prefer this way. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this, if you're a fan of list comprehensions like I am:

```
params = [param1,param2,param3]

query_array = ['query%d=%s'%(ii+1,param) for ii,param in enumerate(params) if param]
url += '?'+'&'.join(query_array)
```

This will eliminate the need to check all the params individually to see if they exist

Comment: You need a '?' before the parameters.